# Puppeteer: Network.response received is missing initial redirects, traffic when opened on the new tab

Tags: networking, browser, puppeteer, headless

The use case I'm trying to cover is to read all the traffic from each tab. I'm not controlling the tab page creation and users can create tabs at any time by clicking.
Listeners set on the page level for each page like

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

 page.on("request", (request) => {...

 page.on("requestfinished", async (rq) => {...
```

I'm using `puppeteer.connect(...` method (but the same issue occurs with regular `.launch(...` too) and the actual scenario is when I connect puppeteer and navigate to the link or HTML on the initial/first tab it catches everything.

1 - When user clicks on link with target=_blank and the link has initial redirects. Puppeteers will just miss those and attach late;

2 - When the user does a right click and open on new tab, puppeteer will miss those initial redirects/requests.

Currently, I'm using puppeteer's cdp connection on the browser level and fetch API to catch those redirects, but fetch API has way less details that I need compare to cdp network API.

Running puppeteer 19+ if it matters.

TIA